# add zeros in money field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with my database on sql server and I'm showing a money type record that will be the total money, the problem is that when I'm doing the data rendering, in the total field it shows me this way 347.0 when in the database is saved with two decimals in this way 347.00 how could you make it show the two decimal places instead of one? Is there a gem that automatically recognizes when the field to be displayed is of the money type so that it can show decimals?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Rails' [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) helper, which formats the proper number of decimal places as well as the currency symbols:

For example (from the docs):

> ```
> number_to_currency(1234567890.50)                    # => $1,234,567,890.50
> number_to_currency(1234567890.506, locale: :fr)      # => 1 234 567 890,51 €
> ```

and check out the `:format` option if you don't want the currency symbols:

> Sets the format for non-negative numbers (defaults to “%u%n”). Fields are %u for the currency, and %n for the number.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want the currency symbol, it looks like there's a [`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) helper:

Examples (again from the docs):

> ```
> number_with_precision(111.2345, precision: 2)                           # => 111.23
> number_with_precision(13, precision: 5)                                 # => 13.00000
> ```